# How to $_GET multiple checkbox values?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, get

```
<input type="checkbox" name="currency" value="usd"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="currency" value="euro"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="currency" value="cad"/>
```

Im trying to get currency values through $_GET request, something like `/?currency=usd,cad` but instead im getting `/?currency=usd&currency=cad`
and then `$_GET['currency']` returns only one value.

adding `name=currency[]` just gets `/?currency[]=usd&currency[]=cad`

What is the proper way to get these checkbox values in some sort of array?

Comment: Put them in a array and then loop through it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="usd"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="euro"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="cad"/>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
foreach($_GET['currency'] as $currency){
  echo $currency."<br/>";
  //or what ever
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
    name="currency[]"

We have to tell the serverside that this is a name with multiple value.

$_GET['currency'] have to be an array this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, make the checkbox name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="usd"/>
```

This will add the check values to an array.  Your method, each check is overwriting the last in your `$_GET`